# how to show side bar on left side using bootsrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap. I m having header and footer, in between that I want to show side bar on left side. I am new to bootstrap and angular js. please guide me how I can build this type of structure.

Comment: Just make content division and add two divs with float:left  gives them width as per your need.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 0):

Try this....

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            Sidebar
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            text
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also learn basic Boostrap: http://getbootstrap.com/

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your problem there Priyanka kakade.
If you want a navbar on the left of your content, you can use this kind of structure between header and footer :

Example :

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-2">
            <!-- navigation -->
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-8 col-md-10">
            <!-- content of the page -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I recommend you use `xs` (mobile display) and `md` (desktop display) classes together, otherwise your navigation would be too little on mobile devices, or too big on computers.